# Computing $T^5(2x+1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let T be a transformation from $P2$ to $P2$ where $P2$ is the space of all polynomials with degree no more than $2$. $T$ is defined by 
>   \begin{align}T(1) &= -3x-1\\
> T(x) &= 4x\\
> T(x^2) &= 2x^2+x+1\end{align}
>
> a) Choose a basis in $P2$ to make the matrix of $T$ diagonal.

For this problem I got the eigenvalues to be $-1, 4, 2$. So the basis would be 
$$
        v_1 = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        5 \\
        3 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
v_2 = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
v_3 =   \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and the diagonal matrix would be 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 4 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

> b) Compute $$T^5(2x+1)$$

How do I do this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have found that if $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the initial basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$, then you have that 
$$A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$$
where $P$ is the matrix with columns the eigenvectors you have found (with the order of the columns corresponding to the ordening of the eigenvalues in $\Lambda$).

Now we have that $$T^k = \underbrace{T \circ T \circ \ldots \circ T}_{k \text{ times}}$$ and composition corresponds to matrix multiplication. So if you want to compute $T^k$, then you have to compute $A^k$. This seems to turn out into a very long computations! However, you are lucky: $A$ is diagonizable and you can show that for a diagonal matrix $D$ you have that $D^k$ is the diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements raised to the power $k$. Hence we have that
$$A^k = \underbrace{(P \Lambda P^{-1})(P \Lambda P^{-1})\ldots (P \Lambda P^{-1})}_{k \text{ times}} = P \Lambda^k P^{-1}$$
since we can cancel out $PP^{-1}$ in the large product. Does this help you in computing $T^5$ and applying it to $2x+1$?

Comment: After I calculate T^5 would I multiply by (2x+1) or would I have to do a change of basis on it to get (7/5x+1/5) and then multiply?

Comment: @Fate no change of basis is needed since you have computed $A^5$, which is the matrix with respect to the initial basis.